# Regex that does not repeat the same character 2 times in a row

Tags: regex

I need to make a regex to validate an amount in which it only accepts numbers, points (.) Optional, 1 comma (,) optional and that after the comma I have at least 2 more numbers, the farthest I've come is this

```
^(([0-9]{0,})+([.]?))+([,]{0,1}?)([0-9]{1,}?)+$
```

This works fairly well, the problem is that it allows me to put the period (.) Followed more than once for example (100 ... 000), this accepts it, but I need it to only accept one period (.) At a time, how do i fix it?

I need the regex to validate as follows

```
100 VALID
100.000,00 VALID

100. INVALID
100..00 INVALID
100, INVALID
100..000,00 INVALID
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To prevent the same character (in this case a dot) appearing consecutively, use a negative look ahead anchored to start of input:

```
^(?!.*[.][.])<rest of regex>
```

In your case:

```
^(?!.*[.][.])(([0-9]{0,})+([.]?))+([,]{0,1}?)([0-9]{1,}?)+$
```

See [live demo](https://rubular.com/r/MED2PuyWkmdC3S) with test cases from question.

---

I'm not clear on what you actually want to match, but I don't need to understand that to answer your question, which  was  how to  prevent the same character appearing consecutively.